# Input type box width should auto scale according to label content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my scenario:
This page will be translated into different languages.
I want the input type box width should be auto scaled as per translated "search" text without changing CSS / structure. [image]

Comment: Try with min or max width.

Comment: `display:inline-block` doesn't work?

Comment: Unfortunately not, do you have an example?

Comment: Hey, it's not french %)

Comment: good eye, it was my bad:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a way for your box model to adapt automatically. Using CSS table layout may serve your purpose.

HTML

```
<div class="input-row">
    <label for="myInput">Search</label>
    <input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="text input"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.input-row {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.input-row label {
    display: table-cell;
    width:1%;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.input-row input {
    display: table-cell;
    width:100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/836c154c/

Answer (score 2):

Please check

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="right">ASaasasasAaA</div>
    <div class="left"><input type="text" style="width:100%"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.container {

    height:200px;
    border:1px solid;
}
.left {
    width:auto;

    background:red;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.right {


    background:blue;
    float:left;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A8zLY/2778/)

Comment: Both of the other solutions suggested **are clearly superior**.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can align items with a new way, with help of flexbox:

HTML:

```
div {
    display: flex;
}
```

CSS:

```
label { white-space: nowrap; }
input { width: 100%; }
```

1. Demo http://jsfiddle.net/infous/710nz58m/
2. http://autoprefixer.github.io/ to get browser prefixes